# How to drop Materialized view in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse, materialized-views

How to drop materialized view in Azure Synapse Analytics ?

I tried `DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW [schema_name].[table_name]` but it did not work. I also attempted to find the doc regarding this but surprisingly, there are none.

Comment: What does "but it did not work" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ALTER` to drop the materializes view.

Syntax:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name
{
      REBUILD | DISABLE
}
[;]
```

Example:

`ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW My_Indexed_View DISABLE;`